# how to add an Id to each row in dictionary ? python

Tags: python

I want to change my data from a dictionary without id's to [(id,'string'),(id2,'string 2'),...]
[image: Data transformation]

Comment: `mydictionary` is a list containing a set as its only element, and `wanted_dictionary` is a list of tuples. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `"mydictionary"` is a set inside of a list:

```
mydictionary = [{'errors', 'wonderful'}]
mydictionary = mydictionary[0]  # now is just a set (out of the list)
# Then we "unpack" with a list comprehension
wanted_dictionary = [ (i,key) for i,key in enumerate(mydictionary)]
```